# I deleted a rails gem in the wrong way - what should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I installed rspec 2.0 beta 22 and then I deleted the folder in the library folder on my mac (I know i'm an idiot).

Now I can't reinstall or uninstall.

HELP!!

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message you are experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

Manually unpack the files from the gem (or copy them from elsewhere, eg another computer). After this, uninstall the gem to get a clean state. You may now reinstall it if you want to keep it.

Unpacking should be easy, as a gem file is just a tar with meta information and data file inside:

```
$ tar xvf gemfile.gem
data.tar.gz
metadata.gz
```

Extract the `data.tar.gz` and copy the lib directory back to the location you deleted before. Look at the other gem directories to find out about the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I was running it from the directory. Problem solved.

Comment: This answer is very terse... What is "it"? BTW: Click "accept" if an answer solved your question.